# C# Generics and using the non-generic version from typed method

Tags: c#, generics, restsharp

I'm using the RestSharp library to access a REST API.

I want all the API requests to go through the same method, so I can add headers, handle errors and do other stuff in a central place.

So I made a method that accepts a generic `Func<>` and that solves most of my problems, but I don't know how to handle the case where I don't have a return type.

```
private T PerformApiCall<T>(RestRequest restRequest, Func<RestRequest, IRestResponse<T>> restMethod)
{
    var response = restMethod.Invoke(restRequest);
    //handle errors
    ....

    return response.Data;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
var apples = PerformApiCall(new RestRequest('/api/apples'), req => Client.Execute<List<Apple>>(req));
```

But I came across a problem, a bunch of API calls don't have a return type because they don't return data. So I used `Client.Execute(req)` and I get the error saying the type arguments cannot be inferred, I tried to pass , but that failed because it couldn't convert the non-generic `IRestResponse` to the typed one.

Any ideas on how to tackle this in a nice way?

Comment: Would creating an overload that takes `Action<RestRequest>` as a second argument help?
`private void PerformApiCall(RestRequest restRequest, Action<RestRequest> restMethod)`

Comment: @robobot3000: I think he still needs to use the return value (of non-generic type `IRestResponse`) to do error handling. If he switches to `Action`, there will be no way to access the response.

Comment: @voithos `don't have a return type because they don't return data`. There is nothing to use if there's nothing returned.

Comment: Why not overload with a `Func<RestRequest, IRestResponse>`?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: What about HTTP status codes? Content type? Headers? Error messages?

Comment: @voithos Of course .. but that isn't part of the OP's question. It could very well be handled in the `//handle errors` part of the  OP's question .. and be acceptable within their application.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: The reason he's passing a `Func` is so that the application code can return an `IRestResponse` _for_ his `PerformApiCall` function. If it was an `Action` instead, there would be nothing for the `// handle errors` part to work with.

Comment: @voithos Thats a fair assessment. I retract my previous statements :)

Comment: @voithos is correct, I do need the response because that's where I get API-specific errors, HTTP status code, etc.\

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I thought about it (and tried to do it), but how do I reuse the code in that case? Overloaded methods will have the same problem where they can't call one method from another because of the generics issue

Comment: @Madd0g Sometimes we try to abuse our code in ways just so we (god forbid) dont disobey the DRY principle. It seems like your case has actually two different needs, one returns a type and the other doesn't. Seems totally appropriate to use an overload.

Comment: Yeah but the difference between them is so minimal, it should be easier. I have multiple catch clauses around `restMethod.Invoke` and if I do it from two methods, that means duplicating *a lot of code*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is to add an overload to your `PerformApiCall` function that takes a `Func` with a non-generic result type, and returns nothing:

```
// Notice the `Func` has `IRestResponse`, not `IRestResponse<T>`
public void PerformApiCall(RestRequest restRequest,
                           Func<RestRequest, IRestResponse> restMethod)
    ...
```

Then, depending on how complex your error checking/logic is, you could move it out to a separate method (which returns the response), and call it from both overloads of `PerformApiCall`:

```
private T PerformRequestWithChecks<T>(RestRequest restRequest,
                                      Func<RestRequest, T> restMethod)
    where T : IRestResponse
{
    var response = restMethod.Invoke(restRequest);
    // Handle errors...
    return response;
}

// You can use it from both versions of `PerformApiCall` like so:
//
//     // From non-generic version
//     var response =
//         PerformRequestWithChecks<IRestResponse>(restRequest, restMethod);
//
//     // From generic version
//     var response =
//         PerformRequestWithChecks<IRestResponse<T>>(restRequest, restMethod);
//     return response.Data;
```

You were getting a compiler error because it is sound to treat a *subtype* as if it was an instance of its *supertype*, but it is not sound to do it in the other direction (which is what was happening when you changed your calling code to just `Client.Execute(req)`, returning a non-generic).

Here's an ideone paste illustrating this: http://ideone.com/T2mQfl

Comment: that's a great solution that has code reuse problems (I just commented about it in the OP), it's too bad I can't reuse the code inside one of the methods. If there's no better way, I'd probably do this.

Comment: I thought about it some more and it's not a great solution because I still need to call the `invoke` twice (generic and non-generic), that means duplicating logic around the invoke (there is error handling - like try and catch around the call, which I can't abstract out).

Comment: @Madd0g: I edited it to address what you mentioned. It's a little heavy-handed, but it _does_ seem doable using generics. You could also add a `where` clause to constrain the generics, as well. Whether or not it's better as far as clarity goes, it probably depends on exactly how much code you'd be duplicating otherwise.

Comment: I made it work and pretty happy with how it looks and works. Thanks!

Comment: @Madd0g I'm pretty curious, did you mimic the exact solution voithos proposed or did you come up with something a little different? Can you update your OP to show us what it looks like, please?

Comment: @PatriceGahide - I've used something *very* similar to what the "ideone.com" link has. The only difference is that I included the RestRequest in the Func<> (just like in the question).